# Spark Custom Grid Header Renderer Style

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-spark

I am trying to create a Header for DataGrid which will show the Label and TextInput. The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:VBox paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5">
        <s:Label text="{data.headerText}"/>
        <s:TextInput width="100%" />
    </mx:VBox>

</s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer>
```

It somehow works but the problem is I am loosing the styles on the headers and the background is showing as white instead of the nice grey gradient.

I think I have to add the styling manually. Is there an easy way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Styles are handled by ActionScript code in the item renderer. It's up to you to write that code in your own item renderer. For an example view the source code for the default header renderer. Or you can ignore styles, and just add a Rect behind the Vbox and set its fill properties to  whatever you like.